# Sending MongoDB data into an array in React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb

I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing with how I'm trying to import my MongoDB data into a ReactJS array. It's had me stuck for the past day or so and I can't figure it out for the life of me. Here's what I'm doing so far to try to bring it in
(The data being imported is a MongoDB collection with two entries, code and name)

```
    // find the course object with the id route parameter
    let course:(Course | undefined) = courses.find(item => item._id === id);
    let courseArray:any[] = [];
    const checkCheckboxes = () => {
        if (course !== undefined) {
            for (let i:number = 0;i < courses.length;i++) {
                courseArray.push({course.code + course.name});
            }
        }
    }
```

Courses collection in question:

```
// drop collection if already exists
db.courses.drop();
// insert new documents into collection
db.courses.insert([
    {
        "code":"WEBD1000",
        "name":"Website Development"
    },
    {
        "code":"PROG2700",
        "name":"Client Side Programming"
    },
    {
        "code":"INET2005",
        "name":"Web Application Programming I"
    },
    {
        "code":"WEBD3000",
        "name":"Web Application Programming II"
        
    },
    {
        "code":"PROG3017",
        "name":"Full Stack Programming"
    },
    {
        "code":"APPD1001",
        "name":"User Interface Design & Development"
    },
    {
        "code":"WEBD3027",
        "name":"Developing for Content Management Systems"
    },
    {
        "code":"PROG1400",
        "name":"Intro to Object Oriented Programming"
    },
    {
        "code":"PROG1700",
        "name":"Logic and Programming"
    }
]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you console.log courses please?

Comment: I guess you can try something like that `Array.from(courses).find(...)`

Comment: Sure thing, I'll bring up the courses database in the post, one moment
EDIT: There it is as it exists in MongoDB

Comment: I mean, can you `console.log(courses)` on the front side (reactjs) not what you insert :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
let course:(Course | undefined) = courses.findOne({_id: ID_GOES_HERE});
```